# How to know that which attributes are returned while creating an aws resource from aws sam template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, sam

For example

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
    sam stack

Resources:
 MyLambdaFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
   Properties:
     CodeUri: lambda_functions/my_lambda_function_code/
     Handler: index.handler
     Timeout: 15
     Runtime: nodejs14.x

Outputs:
 MyLambdaFunctionArn:
   Description: "Arn of MyLambdaFunction "
   Value: !GetAtt MyLambdaFunction.Arn
```

in the above template, when `MyLambdaFunction` is creating,I know that it has an attribute called `Arn` and I can use that like this `MyLambdaFunction.Arn`. I want to know how many more attributes are returned after creation of a resource.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the return section for every resource in the CloudFormation documentation.

In this case, [Serverless::Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html#sam-resource-function-return-values) only has the ARN as a return value.